# MVC View do not select null value in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

if I edit an element it is possible that the carrierId is null. The controller send the null value. But the view selects the first available value from the dropdownlist and not the null value.

I want that if the value is null no element in die dropdownlist is preselected.

View:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CarrierID, "Carrier", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarrierID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CarrierList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarrierID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Model model= ModelService.Get(id);
        if (model== null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.CarrierList = new SelectList(db.User, "ID", "Name", model.CarrierID);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: That's the default behavior, to select the first item.  What is the text and value of your null item look like?

Comment: If the value of property `CarrierID`matches on of your options values, then that option will be selected. And there is no point adding the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor - its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method which internally builds another `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` based on the value of the property.

Comment: And what is `transportOrder`? (that does not match your model)

Comment: And you can use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarrierID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CarrierList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })` to generate a `null` option which will be selected if the value of `CarrierID` is `null` or does not match an option.

Comment: Yeah your right. This do it:  `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarrierID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CarrierList, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add "" to  DropDownListFor** 
become like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarrierID, (SelectList)ViewBag.CarrierList,"", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```